# Compiling angular2 project in production changes code outcome

Tags: angular, typescript

I deployed an angular2 project yesterday and stumbled upon a weird behavior.

When I compile the project in production mode the result of a function changes( compared to dev).

I checked the data coming from the api and its the same.

Is the uglyfier or something else messing up my code? Or could someone explain me what exactly happens when I add "`--prod`" to the "`ng build`" command?

Function:

```
generateData(data: Call[]): void {
    let result: CallHelper[] = [];
    let counter: number = 0;

    this.timeSeries = ['x'];
    this.chartData = ['Calls'];

    data.forEach((c) => {
        result.push({ date: c.start_date, value: 1 } as CallHelper);
        result.push({ date: c.end_date, value: -1 } as CallHelper);
    });
    result = result.sort((a, b) => {
        return moment(a.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').diff(moment(b.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
    });
    let lastDate: string = "";
    result.forEach((d) => {
        counter = counter + d.value;
        if (lastDate == '' || d.date != lastDate) {
            this.chartData.push(counter);
            this.timeSeries.push(moment(d.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:SS'))
        }
        else {
            this.chartData[this.chartData.length - 1] = this.chartData[this.chartData.length - 1] + d.value;
        }

        lastDate = d.date;
    })
    console.log(this.timeSeries);
    console.log(this.chartData);
}
```

Output comparison:

[image: Result Array]

Sample input data from the api:

```
[
 {
  "id":751000375,
  "start_date":"2019-01-19 08:05:42.0",
  "end_date":"2019-01-19 08:08:54.0",
  "wait_seconds":28,
  "connect_seconds":164,
  "afterwork_seconds":56,
  "total_seconds":220,
  "incoming_number":"*********",
  "connected":true,
  "in_advanced_time":false
 },
 {
  "id":751000391,
  "start_date":"2019-01-19 08:16:59.0",
  "end_date":"2019-01-19 08:17:28.0",
  "wait_seconds":5,
  "connect_seconds":24,
  "afterwork_seconds":116,
  "total_seconds":140,
  "incoming_number":"*******",
  "connected":true,
  "in_advanced_time":false
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I got an hint to change this line  `if (lastDate == '' || d.date != lastDate)` to this one `if (!lastDate || !lastDate.isSame(moment(d.date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS')))` and now it works. It doesnt explain why it worked without production flag but it works.